# `tftp` command in U-Boot: Binary image or U-Boot image?

Tags: bootloader, u-boot

When using the `tftp` command in U-Boot, do I have to specifiy a binary image to load, or an image created with the U-Boot-supplied `mkimage` tool?

Addendum: The image I'm trying to load is a bare-metal C program. I compiled it with

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc (input files and flags) -o blinky.elf
```

and converted it with

```
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary blinky.elf blinky.bin
```

.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tftp` command is just for downloading a file from the host, it does not care what to download. The `bootm` command is which does care. Recent versions of u-boot are capable of loading zImage directly (if configured). But the most common way is to use the legacy uImage, created either by `mkimage` or by `make uImage` command, if supported.

Upd:
  For a bare-metal programs you should use the `go` command in u-boot with the address of your `bin` file:

```
tftp ${loadaddr} yourfile.bin
go  ${loadaddr}
```

Upd2:
 By the way, It is possible to build u-boot with a `bootelf` command, which will allow to boot from your output `elf` file, without the need of using `objcopy`.

Comment: I suppose I should have mentioned, that the file I'm trying to load is not a Linux image. (See my amendment in the question.) It's a bare-metal program which is running fine when getting *flashed* directly into the SRAM through the debugger.